# Output behavior of CMOS

Tags: cmos

Assume a CMOS-cell, which is an inverter(?) here and hence, the input is connected to both transistors, but please let's treat the transistors independent from each other.

```
V_0 = 5 V, when upper transistor is conducting and lower not.
V_0 = 0 V, when lower transistor is conducting and upper not.
```

What is `V_0` in case both are conducting?

[image: img]

Comment: Something to think about: what input voltage would make both transistors conducting? What is the problem when both transistors are conducting?

Comment: I don't understand the first question. Do you mean the value? Seen in logic levels, I probably would have an unclear state. But which voltage would I have? 2.5 V ?5 V - U_T? 5 V - 2 * U_T? U_T denotes the transistor voltage itself.

Comment: Output voltage depends on how much each of the transistors are conducting, i.e. their Rds is set by their Vgs, so it depends on input voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transfer characteristic of a CMOS inverter would look like this:
[image: CMOS Inverter Transfer Characteristic]

Since we are leaving the realm of digital signals, it is not a matter of which transistors are conducting, but rather how much the individual transistors are conducting. So strictly speaking, both transistors are conducting for most of the input voltage range shown in the graph. The exact voltage depends on the input voltage and the specific transistor parameters.

A state of both transistors conducting significantly is not desirable since you effectively short circuit the supply voltage. Nevertheless this state occurs for a logic transition at the input, but only for a very short time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I was looking! A further question: Why would I short the supply voltage and why is that bad? For me it looks like a "regular" circuit then. A lot of circuits have a connection between supply voltage and ground with lots of devices in between?

Comment: When a transistor is considered turned on, you can view it as a very low value resistor. When both transistors in the inverter would be turned on (e.g. Vin =VDD/2), you have two very low resistances in series across the supply voltage. This causes a high current and in turn a high power dissipation (heat).

Comment: Alright, got it. Thank you!

Comment: Please include a link or citation for the graphic you copied into your answer. We want to give credit to the original creator.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Graphic was taken from lecture notes on "Fundamentals of VLSI-Design" by C. Scheytt at the University of Paderborn Germany. The notes mention "CMOS VLSI Design: A Circuits and Systems Perspective" by Weste, Harris as a general reference, but I could only find similar illustrations in the book and not the same. Any advice how to properly cite this in the post, so that it is useful for other people?

Comment: Lars, the Vdd/2 bias point for common CMOS inverters does cause shoot-through current, but output resistance is *higher* than the low ON resistance, even though you have P-MOS effectively in parallel with N-MOS. This happens when Vout is near half-Vdd for symmetrically-designed inverters.